# How to copy an image from USB Camera to device using Android's MtpDevice class?

Tags: android, mtp

I'm trying to copy the contents of my camera to a tablet (Motorola Xoom, Android 3.2) using the MtpDevice class from the android.mtp package. The specific method I'm using is [importFile(int objectHandle, String destPath)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/mtp/MtpDevice.html#importFile%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) but somehow it always fails (method returns false).

I'm using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() as destPath and the objectHandle that I have parsed before.

Any info would really help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your tablet supports Host MTP/PTP ?
If it supports did you give write permission in manifest file?